# Requesting NEHotspotHelper entitlements permission for Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, hotspot

I'm developing an app that needs to be awoken when the user changes Wi-fi network, in order to make network measurements.
To do this I've added **network-authentication** background mode in Info.plist, and used NetworkExtension framework:
`[NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:options queue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) { }`.
In order for **registerWithOptions:options** to work I need that Apple to grant permission for the NEHotspotHelper entitlements. I made a few requests to Apple to grant this permission and each time, no matter what I've completed in request form, I got rejected.

My question is what is the best way to request these permissions? or what is the proper use case of an app to grant this permissions, and if someone had success doing it, a little help with some hints would help me a lot.

Thanx.

Comment: It seems that your use case doesn't meet Apple's requirements for this entitlement

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your response. I realised that i don't meet their requirements, that's why I requested help of what will be the best use case to get this permission.

Comment: I don't think you will. The only suggestion we could give here is to change your app to one that meets the requirements; be a carrier or wisp app or an enterprise wifi app; but that's not what your app does.